# Handelbars find helper return object and assign key value to a template variable

Tags: handlebars.js

I add a generic helper to find an item in an Array.

```js
module.exports = function(array, findFunctionString) {
    const fn = new Function("return" + findFunctionString)();
    return array.find(fn)
};
```

My array is like :

```json
[{label: "foo", selected: true}, {label: "bar", selected: false}]
```

What I'm looking now is to get the result and assign to a template variable with a specific key of this returned object.

```
{{#> myTemplate myVar=(find myArray "(el) => el.selected").label}}{{/myTemplate}}
```

I still got an error

```
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'SEP'
```

Yet, if remove ".label", no error, the object is well assigned to `myVar`. But I just want to assign the value of the key `label`.

Why can't I access to the key of the returned object ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use in addition `lookup` helper.

`label=(lookup (find data.languageSelector.options "(el => el.selected)") "label")`